# Can't Upvote or Flag comments on SO & Meta

Tags: bug, status-norepro, javascript, internet-explorer

I can't upvote on comments on SO or here on Meta.  If I mouse over a comment I don't see any option to upvote or flag.

I can upvote and flag comments on SF and WebApps.

Using IE 8 (8.0.6001.18702).

**MY SOLUTION**
For IE8 users who have this problem who also think that clearing your browser cache didn't help:

When you use the Delete Browsing History dialog in IE8, make sure you clear the checkbox for the 'Preserve Favorites website data' option before you click the Delete button!

Of course this won't help if SO isn't in your Favorites.

Comment: (This is a test comment.)

Comment: @Jon - I can't upvote or flag your comment Jon. I don't even see the option to do so. I am able to edit and delete my own comment.

Comment: I can upvote yours. Please edit in your browser info.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  IE 7 on a somewhat locked down network

Comment: This is strange: on another machine (using same version of IE, same network) I can upvote comments on SO but not here. From my original machine I can see I updated a comment on SO but still can't upvote there.

Comment: Using IE 8.0.7600.16385, I can reproduce this. (Was using FF before.)

Comment: @andand I'd say our network is somewhat locked down but there hasn't been any recent change in our security policy. But you're right, the problem could easily be an IE setting.  But then why can I upvote on SO on one machine at work and not another while at the same time neither workstation can do so on Meta.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on IE 8.0.6001.18702. It might be a particular setting that you have on IE. Which remains weird why it would affects some sites and not all. I'm not entirely sure what the cause could be, but I'd start by seeing if you have anything odd on the `.stackoverflow.com` domain, as that's one thing I know that Meta and SO share that SF and Web Apps do not.

Comment: I can't vote either on IE7

Comment: Same here - can't vote comments on IE7 at stackoverflow, meta.SO, programmers, and meta.programmers. I cleared everything, and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce this on Meta and SO, but not SF, as mentioned.

However, I did a full dump of the browsing history, and it works on all sites now. Try that.

Comment: And of course "Delete History" is one of those things locked down here.

Comment: Didn't help me.

Comment: I'm a bonehead. I had IE set to not completely clear browsing history for Favorited sites (like SO + friends). I edited my question with the details on what I did. Thanks Jon

Comment: @Jay: Glad we got it solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser cache is out of date, invalid, or corrupt. Clear all browser cache and try again.

Comment: Local policy won't let me delete the browser history, but I have deleted Cookies, Temporary Internet Files, Form Data and Passwords. Still no joy.