# Has Comment voting changed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, comments, comment-voting

All of a sudden, I can't vote on comments on any StackExchange site. The voting arrow doesn't even appear when I point to where it should be. Is this a change in the site-wide functionality, or is something up with my account? If it's the latter, how do I find out what it is?

In case it makes a difference, I've recently joined several new-to-me SE sites, after having been an active member of SO and a not-so-active member of serverfault for a long time.

**Edit**

In reply to comments, I'm *quite* certain that I'm logged in. The browser is IE7. I'm not real sure how to lear the cache, since I use Firefox most of the time....

**Second Edit**

I've "Delete[d] Browsing History...", eventually doing a "Delete all...". No Joy. FF is *so* much nicer....

**Yet a Third Edit**

I did a full "Reset...". Still. No. Joy.

I will check Firefox when I get home (or maybe tomorrow morning). This is looking more & more like an IE-specific bug.

**And a Fourth**

Works fine in Firefox at home....

**Final Edit**

Works fine now--Thanks!

Comment: Try doing a hard refresh on the affected site(s) (Ctrl+F5), failing that clear out your browser's cache. Which browser are you using?

Comment: This happened to me yesterday but I thought it was probably an IE-only bug that would disappear soon enough. Haven't tried it again since then.

Comment: Is this possibly similar to the issue [discussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71710/cant-upvote-or-flag-comments-on-so-meta)? If so, the suggestion to clear the cache and browser history may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue with how IE7 handled the css rule `display:inline-block` - a fix will be deployed in tomorrow's build.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Clear your browser cache and try again.</s>

Sorry, I can repro this in IE8 in IE7 compat mode. We'll look into it...

Comment: This hasn't worked for me on affected machine/browser combinations.